# Find and replace in specific Excel column

Tags: excel, replace, vbscript

How to modify this script to only find and replace in a specific column?

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.Visible = True
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\test.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set objRange = ws.Range("Q1").End(xlDown).Select
objRange.Replace "~*", ""
```

The current script gives an error on the `Set objRange` line. Replacing `*` in the entire sheet would interefere with formulas.

Comment: Is this Excel VBA or VBScript? If the former, change the tag. If the latter, `ActiveSheet` isn't defined in VBScript.

Comment: This is vbscript as title and tag says.

Comment: A surprisingly large number of people confuse Excel's scripting language with VBScript. Your code uses `ActiveSheet`, which makes more sense in VBA than it does VBScript. If it is VBScript then `ActiveSheet` is just another variable that would need to be set: `Set ActiveSheet = xlApp.ActiveSheet` (replace `xlApp` by whatever variable you are using for the Excel Application). Not quite sure why you are trying to select the column. Ranges don't need to be selected in order to be searched.

Comment: Hi John. I will replace a symbol from this column which should not be replaced in other cells. If activesheet is not appropriate to select the column in vbscript, or if you have better suggestions for this function, it would also work. Activesheet was just my initial thought.

Comment: Unless this code is designed to target an already open workbook in which the user has already activated a user-chosen worksheet, the notion of `ActiveSheet` isn't a natural fit. What sheet contains the data? Just use something like `Set objWorksheet = wb.Worksheets(1)`. If you need to target all sheets in a workbook, iterate over the workbook's worksheets collection with a `for each` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking too complicated. Just tell the `Range` property that you want the entire `Q` column and call the `Replace` method directly on that `Range` object:

```
ws.Range("Q:Q").Replace "~*", ""
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is another and I think easy way to do this:**

Step 1: Select the column

Step 2: Press **Ctrl+H**

Step 3: Enter the value for "**Find What**"

Step 4: Enter the value of "**Replace with**"

Step 5: Click on "**Replace All**"

[image]