# Using VBScript: find and replace characters in specific column of CSV file

Tags: excel, csv, replace, vbscript

I need to find and replace on CSV file the ";" characters to the "|" characters in the "U" `Category` column using VBScript.

[image]

The old string :

```
Premier League;Conference Premier
Conference Premier;Conference North/South;Football League One
```

The new string after CSV replace :

```
Premier League|Conference Premier
Conference Premier|Conference North/South|Football League One
```

I have tried this code without success.

How do I resolve this?

Any suggestion?

My code is below.

```
   Const xlCSV = 6

   Start_Time = Timer    

   Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\p2022.csv")

   objExcel.DisplayAlerts = FALSE
   objExcel.Visible = TRUE

   Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("p2022")   
   lastRow = objWorksheet.Range("U" & objWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).row
   objWorksheet.Range("U2:U" & lastRow).Replace ";", "|"
   
   objWorkbook.save
   objExcel.quit

   End_Time = Timer
   Total_Time = FormatNumber(End_Time - Start_Time, 2)     

   if Err.Number <> 0  then 
      MsgBox("REPLACE : " & Date() & vbcrlf & Err.Number & vbcrlf & Err.Description)   
   else    
      MsgBox("REPLACE : OK! " & vbcrlf & Date() & vbcrlf & "Total Time : " & Total_Time )         
   end if
   
   Wscript.Quit
```

**UPDATE**

I don't have error but this is the new string after CSV replace

```
-1;1;Premier League;Conference Premier;02/02/2022 14:16:56
```

The replace was not performed

Comment: What does *I have tried this code without success* mean? Is there an error? In which line? I think you need spaces around the ampersand character (`&`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find and replace in specific Excel column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40740567/find-and-replace-in-specific-excel-column)

Comment: @VBasic2008 thanks for reply. Please see **UPDATE** on the question

Comment: @user692942 Please don't set the question to duplicate. I have already tried otherwise I would not have asked for help...

Comment: @EdwardSheriffCurtis maybe if you explained that in the question, knowing what you tried is an important piece of missing information. Have you tried just specifying the column range instead of being explicit? e.g. `objWorksheet.Range("U:U").Replace ";", "|"` as the duplicate suggests?

Comment: @user692942 Yes I have tried using `objWorksheet.Range("U:U").Replace ";", "|"` : The output in **UPDATE** on the question

Comment: @EdwardSheriffCurtis The assumption you are making is it's not doing anything, I'm not so sure it might simply not be matching `;` due to an encoding issue etc. Suggest having a look at [the Official Documentation - Range.Replace method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Replace) and go from there.

Comment: Probably should specify the 3rd parameter: `objWorksheet.Range("U2:U" & lastRow).Replace ";", "|", 2`, where `2` corresponds to `xlPart`.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for suggestion. I have specify also the 3rd parameter and I have the same problem

Comment: Is the `;` the separator for this CSV file?

Comment: Does the `;` appear in any column other than the `U` (Category) column? If not, then there's no need to load the file into Excel at all. A CSV file is a text file. Just read the whole file into a variable, replace `;` with `|` and write the data back to the file.

Comment: @BigBen Yes the separator for this CSV file is `;`

Comment: I wouldn't use Excel for this at all tbh. Excel is notoriously bad working with CSVs. My guess is that the contents of column U when you call `Workbooks.Open` aren't actually what you think they are.

Comment: You should show a few lines from the actual CSV file in your question. It's impossible to provide a precise answer without seeing the exact data structure.

Comment: @EdwardSheriffCurtis As myself and BigBen have pointed out, do you know the source encoding in the CSV file?

Comment: @user692942 I know the source encoding in the CSV file

Comment: @EdwardSheriffCurtis Can you share that information?!?

Comment: @user692942 do you mean the record layout of the csv file?

Comment: @EdwardSheriffCurtis No, sorry, I'm asking, is the file UTF-8, is it Unicode, is it Windows-1252 or even ASCII character encoded? Different encodings can play a big part in issues like this.

Comment: @user692942 `UTF-8`

Comment: @EdwardSheriffCurtis that will be the issue as UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding as opposed to single-byte like ASCII. The `Replace()` will be matching a single byte `;` when the `;` in the CSV is multi-byte encoded.

Comment: @user692942 UTF-8 is multibyte for some characters, but not the `;`. An ANSI file of `;` is binary identical to UTF-8 file of `;`. Unless there is a BOM (or at least one multi-byte character), the file cannot actually be distinguished as UTF-8 or ANSI. If the file is UTF-8 with BOM, that could be the tripping point, but it could still be just a matter of data structure. The `;` as (apparently) both separator and data concerns me. I still want to see the data, but at least one sample record has yet to be posted.

Comment: @EdwardSheriffCurtis Please edit the question to include a few lines of the CSV file.